# Can I use controllers together with razor pages i .net core webbapplication

Tags: .net-core, controller

I'm looking into .Net Core 6 Webbaplicaition for the first time. When creating such a project it add razor pages. Is it also possible to use controllers in the same projects, if so is there something special that I need to do to get that to work? I tried to just add a controllera folder and then created a TestController inside that folder, browsed to /Test but that does not work, it does not recognize any page in that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But it's need a specific middleware to work. In "Program.cs" :

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

        // Add services to manage API controller
        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        var app = builder.Build();
        ...

        // Add the middleware to manage API controller
        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also had to add builder.Services.AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine(); in order to get it running. Dont know why but it worked

Comment: Your controller has the attribute [Route]?