Best way to handle the functionality of a partial in aspnet.core razorpages?
I have a partial, which is a table. I want it in a partial because I want to use it, and its functionality, in more than one place, and inside other pages.
From what I can see, there's no way to have some sort of controller dedicated to this partial, nor a shared controller. Therefore, all of the functions to populate the models for the table in the partial seemingly can't be associated with the partial. They need to be duplicated in the PageModel of every page that has the partial.
What would be the best/proper way to achieve what I am asking?

If you want to create a reusable self-contained piece of UI that depends on data or needs its own controller, use a ViewComponent instead of a partial.
These components support DI so you can inject services into them to e.g. obtain data, and they accept parameters too.

Thanks, I saw that, I just need a human with experience to tell me that it was right. I was going this route until you answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73944949/can-i-use-controllers-together-with-razor-pages-i-net-core-webbapplication

The whole reason I wanted to do it this way is because I wanted to be able to refresh the data without reloading the page, and without duplicating code. Seems I still need to duplicate some code if I want to use this, or implement an MVC controller, in which case it makes no difference if I am using a ViewComponent or a partial... unless I am just not understanding something

Oh, you are Mike Brind! You were also discussing this with my colleague here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76541008/6938505 (that's actually what I am looking for too - small world!)

@RabbiKaii The difference between your requirement as stated in your question and your colleague's is that they specifically stated they wanted to call the partial via AJAX.

The issue with the ViewComponent answer is that it cannot post back and forth, so if data needs to be refreshed/filtered etc it's no good.
I ended up going with this comment thread's suggestions, making a proper Razor Page, but having the OnGet() return just Page(), after setting up the Model. I had to make sure to set Layout = null; on the page.
Then I can make a _MyComponentPartial.cshtml in Shared, which can be inserted anywhere, which can use Ajax calls (e.g. in it's document ready function, or to filter/refresh data) to call my Razor Page, and inserts it as HTML into a <Div> with ID of choice. I can add filters and refresh buttons into this partial, and get dynamic functionality out of this component.
